# How to forbid Google Chrome change minimal font-size of my web-page?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, fonts

I'm making responsive sites, and in html tag I have this:

```
    font: normal 10px/1.5 "proxima-nova-soft", sans-serif;
```

So, in other tags I'm use rem for font-size.It's works pretty good and I don't have problems earlier.But today I find issue(my client find).If in Google Chrome settings we change minimal font-size - all pages will be crushed.
Of course I can change web site font to 10px, but it's very bad approach...

Comment: You can't. The user rightly always gets the final say.

Comment: worth designing in `rem`, with media queries to check whether content will overflow, take it from there?